# How can I send multiple requests with different payload?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send multiple requests with threads (with different payload). I made a loop and it works iterating through the list, but it doesn't work with threads, threads just repeat same first account from the list.

```
accs = ["testaccount1:password1", "testacc1:pw1"]

for i in accs:
        username, password, new_email = accs[0].split(":")
        print(username, password, new_email)

def login():
    payload = {'grant_type': 'password','username': username,'password': password,'session-data': '{"browser-name":"Chrome","browser-version":"73.0.3683.103","os-name":"Windows","os-version":"10","device-model":"","device-manufacturer":"","device-name":"Windows"}','client_id': '228TQF','access_token': 'on','enableRefreshToken': 'true','scope': 'movie name type',}
    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post(url, data=payload)
        data = p.content
        data = json.loads(data)
        token = data['access_token']
        print(token)
        print(p.content)
        headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8','Origin': 'https://www.testsite.com','Referer': 'https://www.testsite./settings/','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

t = threading.Thread(target = login, name = 'thread1', args = (14, 'thread1'))
threads_list = []


for i in range(1):
    t = threading.Thread(target = login, name = 'thread{}'.format(i), args= (5, 'thread{}'.format(i)))
    t.start()
    print('{} has started'.format(t.name))

for t in threads_list:
    t.join()

end = time.time()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in your logic that would cause me to expect that this code, if it would run, would produce a different payload for multiple thread executions as you have your `login` method defined.  Maybe you expect `username`, `password` and/or `url` to be different in each thread run, but as the code is here, those variables are undefined and your `login` method won't run at all.

There are enough problems with this code so that I don't see how it can run far enough for your main question to even come into play.  The problems I see are:

You'll get an unpacking error in your first `for` loop, as you're trying unpack a split that will produce 2 items into 3 variables.

You're iterating over the `accs` list, but then you're referring explicitly inside each iteration to `accs[0]`, never using the iteration variable `i`.  Maybe this is the source of your problem, because if you had multiple items in `accs` that unpacked correctly, the use of `accs[0]` would mean you'd print the first entry in the list over and over.

In your `login` function, `username`, `password` and `url` are undefined.

You never start the first thread you define.

You loop with `for i in range(1):`, which will only perform a single iteration, and along with the prior comment, means that you'll only run a single thread.

You create the list `threads_list`, and you try to join based on the contents of it, but you never add anything to it.